# What can be the different values of $_FILES when a PHP upload fails?

Tags: php, upload

This is a typical `$_FILES` array when an upload succeeds:

```php
array (
  'field_name' => array (
    'name' => 'photo.jpg',
    'type' => 'image/jpeg',
    'tmp_name' => '/tmp/xxx',
    'error' => 0,
    'size' => 12345
  )
)
```

Now what the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) fails to mention, is what exactly these array keys contain **when `$_FILES` is populated**, but **the `error` key is not `0`** (`UPLOAD_ERR_OK`)

- Are the 4 other keys (`name`, `type`, `tmp_name`, `size`) **always** present?
- If yes, what is the content of these keys in case of an error:

  - does `size` contain `0`, an empty string, or `NULL`?
  - does `tmp_name` contain an empty string, or `NULL`?
  - is `name` always available, or can it be an empty string or `NULL`?
  - is `type` always available, or can it be an empty string or `NULL`?

Comment: the only value you can trust to be present is `['error']`, **IF** the html form was constructed properly. Check for errors first. If there was an error, then NONE of the other values can be trusted to be present, let alone accurate.

Comment: What Marc said; relying on undocumented behaviour is not a recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by what's present in the simplest of the error cases, `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` (no file was selected):

```php
array (
  'field_name' => array (
    'name' => '',
    'type' => '',
    'tmp_name' => '',
    'error' => 4,
    'size' => 0
  )
)
```

I would extrapolate the following assumptions:

- All 5 array keys are always present;
- `name`, `type` and `tmp_name` will always be `string`s, which can be empty on error;
- `size` will always be an integer, which will likely be `0` on error.

If anyone has a counterexample, I'll be happy to see it!